# KitKat WebView incorrectly reports pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview

On Android, within a webview, we're having an issue in which the `window.pageYOffset` property intermittently returning 0 incorrectly.

It also returns 0 when it should, as in, the top of the page.

Here's a JSBin showing what we have so far (open the console):

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nimejetoseno/1/)

Here's the code we're using:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nimejetoseno/1/edit)

And here's a screenshot of the console.log as the page is being scrolled.

[image: log showing the issue]

Our environment is Android KitKat, using a webview within an application, that the chrome developer tools is reporting as version (33.0.0.0).

Also worth mentioning that we if we load the page within chrome 37 on KitKat it functions as expected, and does not intermittently report 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a solution where you'll have to cache the offset value on scroll, and when the WebView intermittently returns 0 for window.pageYOffset, use the previously cached position.

Here's a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sunez/1/edit) that works in the Android WebView.

Rather nasty regarding performance I know, but implementing an interval or timeout [like this](http://joshbroton.com/hooking-up-to-the-window-onscroll-event-without-killing-your-performance/) will also help.